# Java: Not Catching deliberate BadPaddingException

Tags: java, try-catch, badpaddingexception

My app prompts the user for the password that was used to encrypt a control file.  If the wrong password is entered, the app responds by creating a new control file.  Therefore I need to catch a BadPaddingException so I can trigger the appropriate response.

Here's the code snippet that should generate the exception

```
private void existingHashFile(String file) {
        psUI = new passwordUI(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true, "existing");
        psUI.setVisible(true);
        this.key = passwordUI.key;
        try {
            hash.decryptHashFile(file, this.key); //this is line 240
        } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(homePage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            //then the file was not decrypted
            System.out.println("BPE 2!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(homePage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("BPE 3!");
        }
```

For completeness, here's the decryptHashFile method that is called above

```
public void decryptHashFile(String filename, String key) throws BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, Exception {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        CipherInputStream cis = null;   
        String outFile = filename.replace(".enc", "");
        byte[] byteKey = key.getBytes("UTF-8");

        Cipher cipher = getCipher(byteKey, "decrypt");

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read = cis.read(buffer);
            while (read != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                read = cis.read(buffer); //this is line 197
            }
        } catch (IOException  ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(hashListClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }
            if (cis != null) {
               cis.close(); 
            }
            if (fis != null) {
               fis.close(); 
            }
        }
    }
```

When I deliberately enter the wrong password, I see this stack trace, but my code (I've used a println in the example) isn't executed:

```
Dec 02, 2017 2:31:34 PM appwatch.hashListClass decryptHashFile
SEVERE: null
java.io.IOException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:121)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:239)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:215)
    at appwatch.hashListClass.decryptHashFile(hashListClass.java:197)
    at appwatch.homePage.existingHashFile(homePage.java:240)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`CipherInputStream.read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html#read--) (your line 197) throws `IOException`, not `BadPaddingException`, therefore the exception is caught by the subsequent `catch (IOException  ex)`.

After that you are not explicitly throwing other exceptions, so there is nothing else to catch after `decryptHashFile`.

Comment: Thanks, looks obvious now you've explained it. As I am handling the exception within the decryptHashFile method, my calling method has no chance to run the code-if-bad-password.  So I need to throw the IOException back rather than catch it, I guess?

Comment: you can re-throw it, or just don't catch it in `decryptHashFile`, or return a `boolean success` instead of catching exceptions in `existingHashFile`... it's your choice